# How Can I add description to security group from AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, unix, aws-cli

I am trying to add the IP address to a security group from CLI and I am able to do so, however I am trying to add the description . Can someone support me to know how to add description.

I am trying below way:

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-123456778 --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr `echo "$(curl -s https://checkip.amazonaws.com)/32"` --description "testing"
```

seems the exact command for that to work is as below, but how to pass IP in the same command

The below command is working fine, but is there a way I can pass my cidr using curl? I tried same way as in question but not going trough

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress \ 
--group-id sg-12345678 \ 
--ip-permissions IpProtocol=tcp,FromPort=22,ToPort=22,IpRanges='[{CidrIp=1.1.1.1/32,Description="Testing"}]' --profile xyz
```

Comment: That awscli action doesn't support `--description`. You might be able to do it via `--tag-specifications`. I would build an SG rule manually in the console with a description and then use the awscli to [describe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-group-rules.html) it. Do the results show the description as a tag?

Comment: Thanks, I tried and it does show when we describe in IpRanges

Comment: OK, it's definitely not in the tags. It looks like you supply the description in IpRanges/Description on the `--ip-permissions` parameter.

Comment: The below command is working fine, but is there a way I can pass my cidr using curl? I tried same way as in question but not going trough aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress \ --group-id sg-12345678 \ --ip-permissions IpProtocol=tcp,FromPort=22,ToPort=22,IpRanges='[{CidrIp=1.1.1.1/32,Description="Testing"}]' --profile xyz

Comment: You can use `IpRanges='[{CidrIp='\`curl -s https://checkip.amazonaws.com\`'/32,Description="Testing"}]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress \
    --group-id sg-123456778 \
    --ip-permissions "IpProtocol=tcp,FromPort=22,ToPort=22,IpRanges=[{CidrIp=`curl -s https://checkip.amazonaws.com`/32,Description=\"testing\"}]"
```

Comment: is it the sameway we can pass description as well. like `echo whoami`.

Comment: @WaseemMir Yes, I think so.